# Prototypes or closures for execution consistency and performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, closures

What is the best compromise between performant execution and execution time consistency for method calling in javascript?

I'm still learning javascript and would use prototypes for most everything (i.e. Brendan Eich [here](http://www.aminutewithbrendan.com/pages/20110216)) but I think I'm finding better performance and consistency from function closures (I know I'm probably over optimizing). One prototypal pattern I've been testing:

```
function PrototypeA() {}
PrototypeA.prototype.a = 0;
PrototypeA.prototype.b = 0;
PrototypeA.prototype.someMath = function() {
    this.a += 1;
    this.b += 2;
};
var Test = new PrototypeA();
Test.someMath();
```

Decided after reading this (great!) [post](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/) to benchmark closures. The current closure pattern I'm drifting toward:

```
var SubModule = new((function() {
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var someMath = function() {
        a += 1;
        b += 2;
    };
    return function() {
        this.someMath = someMath
    };
})())();
```

I'm finding that many benchmarks of various patterns are misleading due to errors in the test setup such as calling constructors in the benchmark or calling methods in ways that cause different scope traversal paths. I'm just trying to test method execution.

After lots of benchmarking locally (benchmark.js across many different patterns), I put up the notable patterns:

[Jsperf Here](http://jsperf.com/speedy-pattern-beta)

My findings seem to support that well organized closures don't deviate in execution time as much other types of objects (I use the term "type" loosely). I realize I could be completely wrong due to any number or errors on the benchmark or setup.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Closures and prototypes are completely different animals. It's hard to envisage a situation where you would either want or need to choose between them.

Comment: And `var x = new((function() {...})())();` is a horrendous construction.

Comment: animation is my use case. The SubModule construction is ugly. Its an attempt to avoid object literals and a extra line of code.

Comment: `new` is unnecessary. Try simplifying to `var x = (function() {...})();`.

Comment: Without creating an object I don't get a closure. Is there a different way to create the closure from that constructor without new?

Comment: A closure is formed when a persistent reference to an inner function still exists after its outer function has completed and returned. This can be achieved by assigning the inner function (a) within the outer function, (b) externally, having returned the inner function (as in your "submodule" example). In both cases, the (reference to the) inner function can be assigned directly or contained in an object, which is itself assigned - it makes no difference - a closure is still formed. So, in your "SubModule" code, a closure is formed with or without `new`.

Comment: I don't know why people learning to program are so concerned with testing performance. I wish I understood the tendency, because then maybe I could say something meaningful to prevent it. But, as I do not understand it, all I can try to do is repeat that this is not a good use of your time. Performance issues should be addressed as they arise. Your computer execute *billions* of instructions per second. *Billions!* You're not likely to even know enough to affect performance positively. Just make the damn thing work.

Comment: I'll add that it's pretty clear from your comment about needing an object to create a closure that *you don't yet really understand closures!* You should focus your time on learning the language and abandon your quest to make your (broken) code faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your use case is animation, you want to stick to closures. Simple rule of thumb with javascript is "the more `.` there are, the slower the code goes". In the examples that you posted on jsperf, the slowest ones are the ones that are referencing `this` quite a bit. **Every** time you do that, the engine has to look at the current object and determine whether or not what you are trying to access is available immediately on the object, and if it has to look up the prototype chain. On the closure side of things, you're referencing a rather limited scope, predetermined by the function that is you've written, and the most the engine has to do is be able to look at that scope to reference the variables in it.

Now, there are some gotcha's. First, usage of `this` is significantly faster when you're only referencing it once or twice. Not the case in this example, but it's worth mentioning. The more times you add a reference to `this`, the slower prototype reliant code goes. Look at [this simple perf](http://jsperf.com/simple-closure-vs-prototype) for an example. Second, if you're constructing a lot of these modules (for example, if you're building a data grid), construction is incredibly slow with closures and there's a lot of memory wasted. See [this example](http://jsperf.com/construction-speed) for the speed difference. The more methods and properties you add, the worse it gets. That's because creating a new closure each time makes unique functions and properties, whereas the prototype based one just reuses the same stuff.

In either case, my humble recommendation is to really just look at the situation you're programming for. Most of the time, using prototypes is the way to go - readability [in some cases], re-usability, extendability.. but if they're just too slow, then you just can't use them. That being said, there's nothing wrong with combining the two concepts to give you a reusable and modular setup for methods that don't get hit as often. For instance, try using 'Mixins':

```
var Mixin = {
    interval: 100,
    finish: function () { window.clearInterval(this.intervalRef); },
    start: function (callback) { this.intervalRef = window.setInterval(callback, this.interval)
};

var Module = (function () {
    function getMessage () {
        return "weee!";
    }
    var somethingThatReallyNeedsSpeed = function () {
        var iterations, self = this;

        this.start(function () {
            console.log(getMessage());
            iterations++;
            if(iterations > 10000) {
               self.finish();
            }
        });
    }
    somethingThatReallyNeedsSpeed.prototype = Mixin;
    return somethingThatReallyNeedsSpeed;
})();
```

In this example, construction speed isn't hit as bad due to the prototype just being set to reference the `Mixin` object - there are two methods and a property that the special function does not need to have constructed each time, but it still has available via `this`.

`</rant>`

Comment: really helped clarify things. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is correct or at least correct anymore. When creating different objects with shared structure, prototypes are generally faster since they allow better optimizations. See this example: http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-closures/58

Comment: @JanOlafKrems You're not comparing the same thing. In the demo you've provided, you're calling the `get_name` or whatever which references a variable once. In what I was talking about, there are many references to a variable (be it in closure or on `this`). One reference is faster using the prototype than using the closure, however adding more references to `this` slows it down.

Comment: Fixed your JSPerf to actually use the prototype (create new objects). Prototype is faster, even with many accesses to `this`: http://jsperf.com/simple-closure-vs-prototype/10

Comment: No, you really didn't fix anything. You changed the parameters of the test. The test isn't how fast the accessing can be done after creating the object, the test is how fast can the acessing be done. I've already said that creating objects that define their functions every time is significantly slower. Your new test does not add anything new to the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Scope chain lookup is generally faster than prototype chain lookup: [Scope Chain Lookup vs Prototype Chain Lookup · jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/scope-chain-lookup-vs-prototype-chain-lookup/3)

A few points to remember:

1. Don't ever declare a variable on the `prototype` of a function. It leads to unexpected problems. Only functions must be declared on the `prototype`.
2. If you want all the instances of a function to share a variable declare it as a property of the function itself.
3. Don't ever write code like `new((function() { ... })())()` unless you want people to come after you with pitchforks and firebrands.